# Difference between out of memory and allowed memory size of * bytes exhausted

Tags: php, mysql

I’ve tried to get over a millions of rows from a MySQL table to PHP my application.

Steps to get data are like bellow.

1. Send query to mySQL with mysql_query() or mysqli_query()..
2. Set result to array with looping each rows by using mysql_fetch_array().or add array by using mysqli_fetch_all().

I took messages ‘out of memory’ or ‘allowed memory size of * bytes exhausted’.

I might be able to solve them if I change ‘memory_limit’ .

But I want know why those message was shown.

I’ve changed ’memory_limit’  like 128M-> 512M ->1024M.

When I set 128M,sending query was failed with allowed memory size of *bytes exhausted and I can’t add result to array area.

Then setting 512M, query was finished successfully but I can’t add result to array with allowed memory size of * bytes exhausted.

Finally setting 1024M,both sending query and set result to add result to array was finished .but sometime mysqli_fetch_all() was field with Out of memory.

One thing I can’t understand is why Out of memory isn’t happen constantly?

One more thing I want know is How to get whole rows over a million from a table into PHP less memory turning. After getting whole rows I want let my user to access them by browser operation including download some types of file like csv.

Comment: When you changed the memory limit - did you restart Apache?

Comment: Yes,I did.I resterted Apache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will get "allowed memory size of * bytes exhausted’" when the amount of memory needed exceeds the memory limit specified in php.ini file.

You will get "Out of memory" when the server itself (or Apache or MySQL) runs out of memory.

Comment: These are examples of message when I sat 512M for memory.
Out of memory (allocated 519307264) (tried to allocate 132702048 bytes).
Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2403012 bytes).
So I can interpret them can't I?
I tried 132702048 but I couldn’t unless I‘ve reserved 519307264 caused by mySQL or someone.
I tried 2403012 but I’ve already used 536870912.

Comment: What is the total amount of memory available in the server?

Comment: My server has 4GB physical memory.

Answer (score 1):

The best option to retrieve huge number of rows is to use `limit` and `offset` in your query and loop through them.

This will prevent the memory issues that you are facing.

Comment: Agreed. If you need ALL of the data for creating a CSV, consider writing some rows to the CSV, then fetching new data.PHP should do garbage collection, but you might want to be fastidious and close and result sets / unset variables within the loop.

Comment: Thanks good advice .I’ll do that , But my question is difference between tow cases of memory issue. I mean difference of condition which message is shown.